# AppCode CMD + F12 menu IOS return type

Tags: intellij-idea, app-code, appcode

When I do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> in AppCode I see a list of methods ( nice would be to see properties as well, is this possible? ) but I don't easily see what their return types are to figure out what method I am looking for.

Is there a way to see a list of methods, their return types, and their parameter types ( like you can in Java ), all I see now is the parameter keys and the method names.

Thanks!

Comment: Ook, I can manage now by looking in the .h file but still not ideal :)

Comment: In IntelliJ, parameters and return type are correctly shown, I don't know about AppCode but you may find what you are looking for in the `Structure` view on the left toolbar.

Comment: No, unfortunately that is the same view. It doesn't contain any info about return or method types :(

Comment: cmd+F12 shows only whether method returns a type other than void or not.